# RewriteRule trouble with number of chars

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this rule in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]$  http://www.mysite.com/redirect.php?ql=$0 [L]
```

This rule will work fine for the  address:

- `mysite.com/CSN4`

But not for ones with multiple numbers:

- `mysite.com/CSN42`
- `mysite.com/CSN490`

I'll have always 3 letters followed by anywhere from 1 to 3 numbers.  How can I make the rule work for any of these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a limit (based on your notes) to your number set will fix this:

`RewriteRule ^[A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{1,3}$  http://www.mysite.com/redirect.php?ql=$0 [L]`

Comment: Grrr... I put - between the 1 and the 3.
How to considere frm or FRM or fRm or Frm, ... ? Thanks.

Comment: I have amended the answer to reflect that -- all you need to do is look for a-zA-Z in your set.

Comment: Stange. It doesn't work for FrM2 and fRm2 but works fine for FRM2 or frm2.

Comment: It should work. Here's a proof of concept (and good tool for testing): http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%5BA-Za-z%5D%7B3%7D%5B0-9%5D%7B1%2C3%7D%24&input=FrM2%0AfRm2%0AFrM21%0AfRm21%0Aabc1%0Aab12%0A